# Repetir div com foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, css3

Tenho uma lista de usuários cadastrados exibe os dados mais importantes como nome e email. Criei uma div para exibir esses dados.  Porém, não quero exibir tudo na mesma div, gostaria de criar uma forma de repetir essa div de acordo com o número de usuários cadastrados. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Voce esta usando Razor para gerar as views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiver usando Razor para gerar as suas views, voce pode colocar a criaçao dos divs dentro do loop do `foreach`.

```
@forach(var usuario in ViewBag.usuarios){
    <div>
        @usuario.nome - @usuario.email
    </div>
}
```